# Is the Jordan decomposition for reductive groups algebraic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected affine algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$. It's a known fact that elements of $G$ admit a decomposition into semisimple and unipotent elements. Namely, choose a faithful representation $G \subseteq GL(n,\mathbb{C})$. Then given $g \in G$, the Jordan decomposition states that $g = su$, where $s$ is semisimple, $u$ is unipotent, and $su = us$. The crucial fact is then that $G$ contains both $s$ and $u$, and this decomposition is independent of the representation. Therefore, the decomposition $g = su$, as well as the notions of being semisimple and unipotent, are intrinsic to $G$. Furthermore, the decomposition is preserved by morphisms of algebraic groups.

However, if we allow holomorphic maps of Lie groups, the decomposition is not respected. For example, the exponential map $exp : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^{*}$ sends unipotent elements to semisimple elements!

So this makes me wonder whether the decomposition depends on the algebraic structure of $G$.

For definiteness, here's my question: Let $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ be connected complex reductive groups over $\mathbb{C}$, and let $\phi: G_{1} \to G_{2}$ be a holomorphic group isomorphism. Does $\phi$ preserve the Jordan decomposition?

My feeling is that the answer is yes, and that it will come down to something like $G_{i}$ admitting a unique algebraic structure compatible with the group structure, and any holomorphic isomorphism being automatically algebraic.

Comment: Yes, it's easy to check that any biholomorphic isomorphism $G_1\to G_2$ between reductive complex groups is algebraic. One can suppose $G_1,G_2$ connected. Then one reduces to the case of semisimple groups on the one hand (which is essentially immediate) and the case of tori. Since all $n$-dim tori are isomorphic, we can consider biholomorphic automorphisms of the $n$-tori. At the Lie algebra level we have $GL_n(\mathbf{C})$. To pass to the group it has to preserve the lattice kernel, so we get $GL_n(\mathbf{Z})$ as biholomorphism group and this is algebraic.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Could you give a bit more detail?

Comment: See Proposition D.2.1 in these notes of Brian Conrad for a proof: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/luminysga3.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I upvoted the two answers in the comments but the fact that you are asking also follows easily from [algebraicity of holomorphic representations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27836/algebraicity-of-holomorphic-representations-of-a-semisimple-complex-linear-algeb). Four possible proofs are outlined in the link above. The difference between reductive and semisimple is immaterial: just use the fact that a connected reductive group is a product of a semisimple group and a torus to conclude that it acts algebraically.

Now realize $G_2$ as a Zariski-closed subgroup of $GL_n({\mathbb C})$. This gives you a holomorphic representation $\phi: G_1 \rightarrow GL_n({\mathbb C})$. Its algebraicity explained above seals the deal.

Comment: I don't think it's true that a connected reductive group is a product of a semisimple group and a torus, although it is certainly a finite quotient of such a product.  For example, I think that $\operatorname{GL}_n$ is already not such a product, although it is the quotient $(\operatorname{SL}_n \times \operatorname{GL}_1)/\mu_n$.

Comment: Nonetheless, I think that the spirit of the argument is easy enough to carry save:  just replace $\phi : G_1 \to G_2$ by $G_1' \times \operatorname Z(G_1)^\circ \to G_1 \xrightarrow\phi G_2 \to \operatorname{GL}_n \to \operatorname{SL}_{n + 1}$, where $G_1'$ is the derived group of $G_1$ (which is semisimple).